# Kerberos ticket renewal on Spark streaming job that communicates to Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, kerberos

I have a long running Spark streaming job that runs on a kerberized Hadoop cluster. It fails every few days with the following error:

> Diagnostics: token (token for XXXXXXX: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN owner=XXXXXXXXX@XX.COM, renewer=yarn, realUser=, issueDate=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, maxDate=XXXXXXXXXX, sequenceNumber=XXXXXXXX, masterKeyId=XXX) can't be found in cache

I tried adding in --keytab and --principal options to spark-submit. But we already have the following options that do the same thing:

> For the second option, we already pass in the keytab and principal with the following:
>   'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=kafka_client_jaas.conf -Djava.security.krb5.conf=krb5.conf -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:ConcGCThreads=12' \

Same for spark.executor.extraJavaOptions. If we add the options --principal and --keytab it results in attempt to add file (keytab) multiple times to distributed cache

Comment: Did you pass your keytab to your streaming job?  https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cm_sg_yarn_long_jobs.html

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways that you can do it.

1. Have a shell script that does the keytab/ticket generation on a regular interval.
2. **[RECOMMENDED]** Pass your keytab to Spark with strict access only to spark user and it can automatically regenerate the tickets for you. Visit [this](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/sg_spark_auth.html#spark_kerberos) Cloudera community page for more details. It's just a simple bunch of steps and you can get going!

Hope that helps!

Comment: We tried the first way but it doesn't work for streaming jobs. Got the same error.

Comment: Added second option attempt in the original question

Comment: David, Were you able to solve the issue ? even we are facing a similar issue. did passing keytab and principal in spark-submit solve your problem ?